# ¿Como hacer que un buscador funcione dependiendo la vista en la que se encuentre? (asp.net mvc c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Buen día Gente.

Actualmente tengo un buscador con el siguiente codigo en la View _Layout.cshtml

```
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("ListaUsuarioPaciente", "Administrador", FormMethod.Get, new { 
                    @class= "d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline navbar-search" }))
                {
                    <div class="input-group">
                        @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new {@class = "form-control " +
                       "bg-light border-0 small", @placeholder="Buscar usuario...",
                       aria_describedby = "basic-addon2",
                       aria_label = "Search", id="Busqueda"})
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                            </button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
```

este buscador solo funciona para la ruta /Administrador/ListaUsuarioPaciente

Sin embargo como yo lo tengo definido en el Layout principal pues me gustaria que este se pudiera adaptar para que también funcione para las siguientes rutas:

- /Administrador/ListaUsuarioMedico
- /Administrador/ListaUsuarioAdmin

Quisiera saber si me pudieran apoyar a hacer algo así, se me ocurría hacer algo como el siguiente if que valide donde se encuentra la ruta y de ser así agregar el código del buscador. Se que lo que pondré no es correcto pero es solo para darles una idea de mi problema.

```
@if(Url.Action("ListaUsuarioPaciente")==true){
   //Agregar cada respectivo código de búsqueda
}
```

Espero me puedan apoyar, de antemano agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Utilicé la sentencia

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

que me arroja la url completa ya solo la metí dentro de un if con la instruccion **Contains**

```
if(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/Administrador/ListaUsuarioPaciente")){
       //Codigo
}
```